# Xmpp openfire connection close after login

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am using below code to create connection between android and **xmpp openfire server**.

```
SmackConfiguration.DEBUG = true;
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration configuration = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                .setSendPresence(true)
                .setResource("SmackAndroidTestClient")
                .setConnectTimeout(10000)
                .setPort(Constants.PORT_NUMBER)
                .setServiceName(Constants.SERVER_NAME)
                .setHost(Constants.HOST)
                .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.ifpossible)
                .build();
      AbstractXMPPConnection  mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configuration);
        mConnection.setPacketReplyTimeout(10000);
        mConnection.addConnectionListener(this);
                try {
                        mConnection.connect();

                    } catch (SmackException | IOException | XMPPException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

              try {
                    mConnection.login(mUsername, mPassword);
                } catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

after successfully connecting to server i am trying to login but i am getting **error**.

```
<stream:error xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><internal-server-error xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams"/></stream:error>

AbstractXMPPConnection: Connection closed with error
org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$StreamErrorException: internal-server-error You can read more about the meaning of this stream error at http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#streams-error-conditions
<stream:error><internal-server-error xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/></stream:error>
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1011)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:952)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:967)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Sometime it happens when you try to log in a user that already logged in. so are you trying in the same way you need to change the resource parameter. just random but different.

Comment: @DevendraSingh I have use different username and password but the error is still same.

Comment: @DevendraSingh i used you code from above link but the error is same.

Comment: is your server configured?

Comment: Is there any possibility that might be server side misconfiguration ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112287/discussion-between-devendra-singh-and-naveen-kumar).

Comment: Its server side issue resolved.If you are using openfire version above 4.0 then u need to use jdk 8 and set the java_home variable too.